# vhosts redirects to homepage (using wamp vhost installer)

Tags: wamp

I have just installed WAMP 3 which comes with a vhost setup wizard, which should work, but my vhosts are all redirecting to localhost/wamp homepage. Any suggestions?

my vhosts definitions are as follows

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>s

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wdc
    DocumentRoot "f:/mystuff/company/profordable/projects/company/projects/other/shop/02/www"
    <Directory  "f:/mystuff/company/profordable/projects/company/projects/other/shop/02/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The appropriate line has been uncommented in http config.

Thats about it, any help at all is welcome.

Comment: NOTE: When you try and run a vhost and there is an error with your vhost definition, Apache falls back to the first vhost in the definition file. So something must be wrong with the vhost for `wdc`

Comment: Did you also add an entry to your hosts file `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` for the new vhost? `127.0.0.1 wdc` and `::1 wdc`

Comment: Did you reboot or reload the `dnscache` using `right click wampmanager->Tools->Restart DNS`